# pip freeze > requirements.txt including all system installed packages inside virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv

Bit of backstory, I'm relatively new to Python and development in general and have stupidly been installing project specific packages as system packages. This is now causing me issues when trying to create requirements.txt files for specific projects, inside of virtualenvs.

For example, I've installed Kivy system wide and every time I create a new env with a requirements file I'm getting the below (yes the env is active):

```
$ pip freeze > requirements.txt
$ cat requirements.txt
Kivy==1.9.1
Pillow==2.6.1
Pygments==2.0.1
chardet==2.3.0
colorama==0.3.2
docutils==0.12
html5lib==0.999
kazam==1.4.5
pygobject==3.14.0
python-apt==0.9.3.12
python-debian==0.1.27
pyxdg==0.25
requests==2.4.3
roman==2.0.0
six==1.8.0
urllib3==1.9.1
wheel==0.24.0
```

I've also tried uninstalling Kivy, amongst other things (trying to be cautious here, don't want to remove vital OS packages) but get the following output:

```
$ pip uninstall kivy 
Not uninstalling Kivy at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages, owned by OS
```

So my questions is this:
How can I get my python packages back to default, with only the essential system packages installed (almost like a fresh python install), then how do I prevent the requirements.txt files inside of a virtualenv including the system wide installed packages (I'll be using evn's much better in future so shouldn't have too many system wide packages)

I'd also be interested to find out why `pip unistall kivy` doesnt work (yes, I've tried running this as root also)

Running Debian 8, if that makes any difference

Hope this makes sense and appreciate any advise you may have.

EDIT: So I think I've been doing this whole thing wrong, once I've created the env I've been using `pip install` rather than `env/bin/pip install`. Unless I'm mistaken this is why the packages have been installing globally. Same goes for the requirements file.

Comment: are you running the uninstall inside the virtualenv? If so run it outside the virtualenv.

Comment: nope running from outside with the venv deactivated

Comment: have you tried `sudo`

Comment: yes tried running as normal user, with the sudo command and finally as the root user

Comment: How did you install Kivy? You could always remove it directly `sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy_package_goes_here` but you should really be able to uninstall it the way you installed it

Comment: Removing from the dist-packages directory worked. I can now remove the packages but when I setup the env I'm still getting the system packages, in the requirements.txt?

Comment: you'll have to look for the relevant line in `site-packages/easy-install.pth` and remove it too.

Answer (score 26):

You can freeze just your local packages in each virtualenv by using the `-l` (or [`--local`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_freeze/#cmdoption-l)) parameter

```
pip freeze --local > requirements.txt
```

Comment: This works, thanks. I have noticed that after installing a package in an active env it just shows those packages in the requirements file as expected. However once I deactivate and run the pip freeze command outside the env, the packages I've just installed are shown,along with all the other system packages, is this normal? I thought the whole point of the env was to not install packages system wide? Hope that makes sense

Comment: If this code isn't working, try to deactivate the base env  
$ conda deactivate ,
then run $ pip freeze --local > requirements.txt  ,
and finally, run $ conda activate, to activate the base env again